# Set EditText to percentage of parents's width in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, spacing

I have a LinearLayout class in which I have:

```
TexView | ImageView | EditText | ImageView.
```

I have the last ImageView all the way to the right side of the LinearLayout its wrapped in. The EditText runs very long and in some case pushes the last ImageView out of view (or so it seems to push it out of view).

I want to to have the `EditText` set to a percentage of the total width. I tried using weight with LinearLayout parameters but it seems to cause the view to get all out of wack. For example here it is for the `EditText`:

```java
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpEt = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                             .50f);
```

All the other views follow suit but have lesser weights (.2, .2, .1) and they all add up to 1.0. But the LinearLayout row is never spaced correctly.

Should I find out the width of the parent (which is a ListView) and then set the width of the EditText explicitly based on the parent's width or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are using xml layout. Can you share it to us so that we can point out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure what your linear layout orientation is but im guessing its horizontal. if so try this.

```
LayoutParams textViewParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);
LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
```

This will make the edit text to fill the remaining space between the textview and imageview. If you need something else, just modify the code a bit. When using weights, set the weight or height as 0 for which you are setting weight for.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately did not work. I edited my post based on what you suggested.

Comment: I take that back, it worked now because now I changed the last LinearLayout parameter to WRAP_CONTENT instead of FILL_PARENT. Thanks blessenm!